# MSSQL Resource Governor reinitialization

Tags: sql-server, resource-governor

I'd like to use Resource Governor for resource management depending on a session database.

The problem - application could take data from different databases ( no cross-database requests ).
To avoid bloating ADO.NET connection pool, application connects to `master` database and then uses `USE <DB_NAME>` depending on a web request context.
Connection comes back to the pool when it's not longer relevant. It's by design and is not going to be changed in the near future

Is there any way to use or some kind of `classification function recall` or `resource governor reinitialization` after the connection is established and `USE` context is switched to a desired database?

select @@version

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU24) (KB5031908) - 15.0.4345.5 (X64)   Dec  4 2023 14:44:16   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Comment: Little bit unclear on your question: 1. "*application connects to master database and then uses USE <DB_NAME>*" - What does that have to do with avoiding bloating the connection pool as opposed to just directly connecting to the user database that you want? 2. What issue are you currently facing with connection pooling and Resource Governor?